# How to position Left/Right buttons on top of left/right edges of image?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I've spent several hours trying to correctly position left & right buttons in the correct place for any image I load.  Here's an example of the way they should look:
[image]

I have a React component called `FullSizeImage` that is correctly centered, horizontally & vertically in a modal that covers 100% of my browser window.  Now what I want to do is add a left button and a right button, have them vertically centered, and positioned left & right respectively over top of the image.  But no matter what I've tried, I can't get it working!

Here's some sample layout code:

```
<div className={styles.container}>
  <div className={styles.buttonContainer}>
    <div>
      <Button type={ButtonType.Circular} text='<' onClick={() => {}} />
      <Button type={ButtonType.Circular} text='>' onClick={() => {}} />
    </div>
  </div>
  <img src={`${item.path}${transformation}/${item.name}`} alt={item.name} />
</div>
```

I have complete flexibility how I introduce those two buttons in relation to the `img` element.

Any ideas how to do this properly - ie. HTML layout and corresponding CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Have the buttons and image in the same container. Use `position: absolute` on the buttons.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.smaller-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.img {
  width: 500px;
}

.left-button, .right-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  translateY(-50%);
}

.left-button {
  left: 0;
}

.right-button {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="smaller-container">
    <button class="left-button">left</button>
    <button class="right-button">Right</button>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3e/Lupine_R01.jpg/475px-Lupine_R01.jpg" alt="flower" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, Richard, but your solution doesn't work.

Btw for my use case you can't specify anything about the image width/height in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of completeness, and helping others, I simplified things and found a solution:

```
<div key={`${item.mediaId}_large`} className={styles.main}>
  <img src={`${item.path}${transformation}/${item.name}`} />
  <div className={styles.leftButton}>
    <Button type={ButtonType.Circular} text='<' onClick={() => {}} />
  </div>
  <div className={styles.rightButton}>
    <Button type={ButtonType.Circular} text='>' onClick={() => {}} />
  </div>
</div>

.main {
  div {
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50vh;
  }

  .leftButton {
    left: 10px;
  }
  
  .rightButton {
    right: 10px;
  }
}
```

Originally I thought it would be cool to have the left/right buttons superimposed on every image but I'm entirely content with having them on the edges of the viewport.

Here's the end result:

[image]